# Spring MVC session Attribute set intially

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have used the Spring MVC. I set the Session Attribute value like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String initHome(Model model) {
            if (!model.containsAttribute("clientObject")) {
                model.addAttribute("clientObject", createDefaultClient());
            }
            return "homeMenu";
        }
```

It is working fine if i click the home menu url(/home). but if i did not go the 
home means it says error as 'session attribute clientObject is required'

so i decided to set sessionattibutes in constructor of controller

```
 @Autowired
    public MyController(Model model) {
       if (!model.containsAttribute("clientObject")) {
            model.addAttribute("clientObject", createDefaultClient());
        }
    }
```

it also says error

`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myController`'

I tried to set using the RequestMapping also like

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void initController(Model model) {
       if (!model.containsAttribute("clientObject")) {
                    model.addAttribute("clientObject", createDefaultClient());
                }

    }
```

this method is also not called intially 
my cointroller look like

```
@RequestMapping("/sample")
public class MyController {
    ..
    ..
```

is it possible to set the sessionAttribute value in the constructor of controller? or any other way to set the session Attribute initially?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: sorry use-case means? I have to set the session attribute value when the controller is loaded

Comment: You can't. The controller may be loaded long before first session with user will be initiated. Controller's lifecycle is wider then session's one.

Comment: then how can i set the session attribute value which is used by all the request mappings in the controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `createDefaultClient` is in the controller add a `@ModelAttribute` annotation to it.

```
@ModelAttribute("clientObject")
public ClientObject createDefaultClient() { ... }
```

This method will be called before any request handling method (as explained in the [reference guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods))

If you combine that with a `@SessionAttribute` annotation on your class (which you might already have). You should be able to achieve what you want.

In your request handling methods (methods annotated with @RequestMapping) you can now simply inject the client object as a method argument.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initHome(@ModelAttribute("clientObject") ClientObject clientObject) {
    // Do something with the clientObject
    return "homeMenu";
}
```

This will only work consistenly within the same controller, so if you need the `ClientObject` to be used somewhere else (another controller for instance), this isn't going to work (nor is `@SessionAttributes` designed for that).